# Modifying a list with user input, selecting the item by index

Tags: python, list

How can I select an item from this list by it's index and modify it back to the list with an update?

```
mylist = ['CHECK EMAIL', 'OPEN PROJECT', 'PRIORITIZE PROJECT']
i = 1
for list in mylist:
    print i, list
    i = i + 1

while True:


    elif ToDo == 'R':
        index = raw_input('What would you like to remove from the list?').upper()

        if index in mylist:
            mylist.remove(index)
            print "It has been removed. What would you like to do now?\n"
            print "Your New ToDoList :"
            print"-----------"
            i = 1
            for index in mylist:
                print i, list
                i = i + 1
        else:
            print "THAT doesn't exist in this list!! Try again!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two parts in that question:

*"How can I select an item from this list by it's index"*

Assuming `index` is the index, and `mylist` is the list, this is achieved with `mylist[index]`. Obviously, `index` has to be (at least) an integer. In your current code, it comes from `raw_input` that returns a string. So convert that string to an integer using, e.g., `index = int(index)`.

*"and modify it back to the list with an update?"*

Assuming `x` contains the new value: `mylist[index] = x`.

If you want to first remove the item, keep going on with `mylist.remove(index)`, and if you want to insert something new at that same position, use `mylist.insert(index, x)`.

More on lists: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html (Python 2, as you used `print i, list` and not `print(i, list)`. I suggest you to move to Python 3 as well).

Comment: Your response helped me to add int(). It is what I needed to add. I don't know why I didn't think to do this!

Answer (score 0):

## Please try below code .. i hope it meets your requirement.

mylist = ['CHECK EMAIL', 'OPEN PROJECT', 'PRIORITIZE PROJECT']
i = 1

for list in mylist:
    print(i,list)
    i = i + 1

while mylist:

```
index = int(input('What would you like to remove from the list? \n'))
print(index)

if index <= len(mylist):
    del mylist[index - 1]
    print("It has been removed. What would you like to do now?\n")
    print ("Your New ToDoList :")
    print("-----------")
    i = 1
    for index in mylist:
        print(i,index)
        i = i + 1
else:
    print("THAT doesn't exist in this list!! Try again!")
```